# SqlConnection.GetSchema("Tables") returns null even though tables exist

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2019

I'm stumped on what could be causing this issue but I can connect to my database by creating a SqlConnection object perfectly fine and open the connection but for some reason when I try to do something as simple as get the schema information for tables schema, nothing is returned.

I've set my connection string in my app.config as follows following the advice from connectionstrings.com

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="pqual_db" connectionString="Server=10.xx.xx.xx;Database=pqual_db;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have the following method in Helper.cs where I am setting the Connection string from the config file.

```
public static string CnnVal(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Lastly, I have the following method in its own class, DbConnect.cs, and this method is called when I click a button on a form.

```
public void GetOs(string osName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("pqual_db")))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable t = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
            string breakpoint = "where i put my breakpoint";
        }
    }
```

I have 15 tables in this database when I look in sql server management studio yet I get a null value for t. Anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is an image of my object explorer in Sql Server management studio. Also worth noting that this db was originally migrated over from mysql using Sql server migration assistant. 
[image]

Comment: Your schema is named "Tables"?  The default schema name is "dbo".  Can you show us your SQL Server Management Studio window listing your database tables?

Comment: @Amy thank you for the response. I have added in the photo and mentioned that I migrated this db over from mysql. Not sure if that would have an effect.

Comment: Okay, this is a misunderstanding.  In your screenshot, "Tables" isn't a schema, it's a category of database objects.  In the SSMS object listing, tables are shown as `<schema name>.<table name>`.  Take a close look at your table listing and notice they contain a dot.  The text before that is the schema name: `pqual_db`.

Comment: your schema is `pqual_db`

Comment: I can see how this could be confusing.  Your database is called `pqual_db` and contains a single schema, *also* called `pqual_db`.

Comment: @Amy I understand that now, however, passing the string "pqual_db" to GetSchema is now resulting in a ArgmentException saying "the requested collection (pqual_db) is not defined. I'm not sure what to make of this as this is indeed my schema name. I guess the question for me is what qualifies as being defined.

Comment: @UCProgrammer Odd.  What does `SELECT name FROM sys.schemas` tell you?  Paste it into your SSMS query window and run it.

Comment: @Amy I get 15 results back pqual_db included